# Can see through strokes in blender grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

For some reason I can see through my grease pencil strokes and fills. How do i stop this.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this video helped me with these kinds of things: <br>
<https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE1IRA-OgcQ>

Answer (score 1):

The stroke here is clearly not cyclic, so filling would probably not occur here.

It would help if you showed a screenshot of your material settings, because chances are, the fill color is also transparent.

Go into the stroke properties tab, enable cyclic on the current stroke, and check that the material fill color is opaque to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

You need change Stroke Depth Order from 2D Layers to 3D Layers:

[image: Strokes]